# how do you amend user input to list and then permanently store that list for future reference in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, input, selenium-chromedriver

I am looking to save the user's input for future reference by my python script.

For example, if the user inputs '11111', if the user ever runs this script again and inputs '11111' the script will know to take a different action due to the input being stored twice.

Sorry if I'm being unclear - what I think would do this is storing user inputs in a list or array, and then before performing an action run a list count to check how many times an input has been used. For example if '11111' appears once in the list do action 1, if '11111' appears twice in the list do action 2, 3 times do action 3 etc...

```
x = raw_input("Enter integer")
integers = [int(i) for i in x.split()]
```

Comment: It's not clear. Please explain the question clearly.

Comment: @TekNath apologies, is it a bit clearer now?

Comment: IS the script running continuously or do you want a solution keeping data every time the script is run

Comment: @Clément every time the script is run, it won't be running continuously

Comment: If you are not running the script continuously then you will have to save the input to a file or a database. When you run your code again, you can read the file/ database and take necessary action.

Comment: @TekNath so I could write the user input to a csv file and then later in the code do a count on how many times the current user input is in the csv?

Comment: @booooooky Yes you can do that.